# iPhone7: Does anyone else show "Phone App" under Location Services?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone7 (iOS 10.1.1) displays a "Phone App" (the icons is the same one that you make calls from) on the Settings > Privacy > Location Services page. My wife has same phone and hers does not. AppleCare does not show this on their lab phones either.

Interestingly, when I first saw this, I only had the choice for "never" share, which was unchecked. So I checked it, but couldn't uncheck it. About 2 hours later, I had 2 additional options "While Using the App" and "Always" for a new total of the standard 3 choices.

Apple is baffled and looking into it. Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: iPhone 6s with 10.1.1 - as soon as I selected Never. The option Always and While Using The App appeared. It's an interesting question. Why would the phone app wanted to have access to location services anyway?

Comment: This must be a bug in some phones. AppleCare checked their lab phones and none of them have it. I would think that phone app would actually ALWAYS need to have location services to assist in tower location, etc. It would be how you can be found by your cell signal in an emergency. I could make an argument, too, for being able to "want" to turn it off altogether. Thanks for your reply.